# how to extract single data of row id and not other from same column?

Tags: laravel

how to extract single data of row id and not other from same column in laravel 5.3 and view it on browser. i have tried an example please see this and give me feedback as soon as possible. thanks in advance.

```
 public function index($id)
{
    $data = $this->issue->find($id);
    if(is_null($data))
    {
        return abort(404);
    }
    $data = DB::table('issue')->select('id','return_date')->get();
    return view('library.after',['issue'=>$data]);
}
```

and this is my view

```
    @foreach($issue as $is)
            {{'<ID="'.$is->id.'" label="'.$is->return_date.'">' }}<br>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Do you have a model for the 'issue' table?

Comment: Seems like you are using repositories, can you include the `IssueRepository` in you question?

Comment: All you want is to return  all of the issues from a table?

Comment: Thank you both for trying to solve the problem. But i found the solution.
 $data = DB::table('issue')->select('id','return_date')->where('id',$id)->get();
 Thank you once again guys

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get only one row then fetch one row from database.

```
public function index($id)
{
$data = $this->issue->find($id);
if(is_null($data))
{
    return abort(404);
}
$data = DB::table('issue')->select('id','return_date')->first();
return view('library.after',['issue'=>$data]);
}
```

in view

```
{{'<ID="'.$issue->id.'" label="'.$issue->return_date.'">' }}<br>
```